# jquery datepicker not appearing in jsf

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, datepicker

I am trying to use a datepicker using native JSF( without any exotic faces) however since I discovered that it doesnt have native support, I have tried to implement it using jquery. However I have tried literally every solution for doing this on the internet, and the datepicker calendar just doesnt show up when i click on the textbox. In the console of the dev tools, it seems to be giving an error of "the method datepicker is not defined". why so? I have literally tried including&excluding every single library. Below is my most recent attempt.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
                          <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#dateOfExpense").datepicker();
    });
        <h:inputText size="20" id="dateOfExpense"/>
```

Comment: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>` is an invalid reference !!

Comment: Use some CDN like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">` and `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`. Make sure you have a working internet connection in that machine.

Comment: Isn't your `id` something like `yourform:dateOfExpense`? My guess is that your selector is wrong.

Comment: @JasperdeVries, that could be true. since jsf auto names it#s elements and form elements weirdly when not named externally, what should I do to make it work?( even though i dont have a form element right now) Shall i use class selector instead?

Comment: @Pugazh Are those all libraries I need to include to make it work(imagine right now i have no libraries imported)?

Comment: You need a form. Use something like `#yourform\:dateOfExpense` as your selector.

Comment: @anant - Yes, jQuery UI library is needed to render `datetimepicker`. You need to first load *jQuery*, then *jQuery UI(

Comment: If i do "inspect element" this is how it is interpreted in the html: <input name="dateOfExpense" id="dateOfExpense" type="text" size="20">

Comment: @Pugazh: tried loading all the libraries. didnt work. Btw do i need to give the form some explicit ID and/or Name too?

Comment: You don't need to explicitly ID your form, but then an ID will be generated. More info on naming containers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo